# Identify Ecobee's 4/5 screens pinouts

Tags: lcd, pinout, touchscreen

Got myself few broken Ecobees thermostats thought to reuse some of the parts in my Arduino/STM32 projects. The question is how to identify screen pinout.

I have few working Ecobees and oscilloscope and in theory i could use them to identify pins but i have never done it before... Any advice or information will be very help full!

Thanks!

[image: Ecobee 4 Screen picture 1]
[image: Ecobee 5 Screen picture 1]
[image: Ecobee 5 Screen picture 2]

Comment: I found some documentations for AVD-TT35HV-NN-046-A, not sure if that is what i have. over all orientation looks same way.

Comment: This video might provide some inspiration for how to reverse engineer an LCD pinout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TedIzmguP0

Comment: Very interesting video exactly what i needed. Thank you @Daniel!

Comment: Did you successfully reverse engineer the ecobee screen pinout? I'm very interested in picking up where you left off. Any documentation appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These may be related if anyone is interested?

https://www.gtk.co.uk/uploads/spec-sheets/TFT035A101A.pdf

and/or this:

https://www.av-display.com.cn/Uploads/attached/file/20200324/20200324101541_57824.pdf

I found them while learning (Read: going down a rabbit hole) regarding tft screens and interfaces.

I was looking to see if I could recycle the ~3.5" tft screen from a Geo Trio II smart meter.

Comment: Looking at the pictures in the question there appear two models (a) AVD-TT35HV-CN-**079-B** which has a 20 pin and a 8 pin FPC (b) AVD-TT35HV-CN-**038-B** which has a 40 pin and a 8 pin FPC. The second link in this answer is for a AVD-TT35HV-**NN-002-S** which might be different, and only has a 39 pin FPC.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/359172)